# AngularJS Guide - Dependency Injection - Factory methods

Tags: angularjs

At the bottom of Angular's [Dependency Injection guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-injection_where-can-i-use-di_factory-methods), I came across this snippet about **factory methods**, and I'm having a hard time understanding where the `"depProvider"` and `"depService"` are being defined:

Here's the snippet:

```
  angular.module('myModule', []).
  config(['depProvider', function(depProvider){
    ...
  }]).
  factory('serviceId', ['depService', function(depService) {
    ...
  }]).
  directive('directiveName', ['depService', function(depService) {
    ...
  }]).
  filter('filterName', ['depService', function(depService) {
    ...
  }]).
  run(['depService', function(depService) {
    ...
  }]);
```

Am I correct in that `'depProvider'` and `'depService'` are injected into these definitions, and would have to be defined elsewhere?  Or are these built-in dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that those are fictional modules that should show you how a factory (or anything else) could **dep**end on another service.

They are no built-in modules or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right. That dependencies can be in the same module or in any module declared as a dependency (modules can have dependencies too).

For what it's worth every Angular built-in service starts with a `$` so they are easily spotted (e.g. `$scope`, `$http`, `$timeout` etc).